# Can I reuse the DNS name of an old Azure classic VM?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I currently have a "classic" virtual machine running on Azure at `foobar.cloudapp.net`.

I'm intending to replace this VM with a newly created VM on azure.
When I try to configure the new VM's DNS name, I  [see this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k5Ad.png) (screenshot), implying that DNS entries for all newly created VM's will end in `.cloudapp.azure.com`.

Is there any way for me to reuse the old VM's DNS name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change the built-in DNS name assigned to a VM. You can create your own in a DNS zone you own and point it at the VM, so if you had done that with the old VM you could have moved it, but not the built-in one.